# Hierarchical Groupby then value count by another column in Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe in Pandas, I want to group by the "name" and then count the number of each rating.

```
Ckey    name    rating
1        Tom      B
2        Tom      A
3        Ken      C
4        Lily     A
5        Lily     A
6        Lily     B
```

expected output

```
name    rating  values_count
Tom        A        1
           B        1
Ken        C        1
Lily       A        2
           B        1
```

my approach doesn't work, please advise

```
df.groupby('name')['rating'].values_count()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
df.groupby(['name','rating']).size()

name  rating
Ken   C         1
Lily  A         2
      B         1
Tom   A         1
      B         1
dtype: int64
```

Or to get it back as a dataframe, use:

```
df.groupby(['name','rating']).count()

             Ckey
name rating      
Ken  C          1
Lily A          2
     B          1
Tom  A          1
     B          1
```

Alternatively, your method works, but use `value_counts()` rather than `values_count()` (just a typo, I guess):

```
df.groupby('name')['rating'].value_counts()

name  rating
Ken   C         1
Lily  A         2
      B         1
Tom   A         1
      B         1
Name: rating, dtype: int64
```